# Upper bound of a matrix square product

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone validate this: $$(F+G)^T P (F+G) \le (1+\epsilon)F^TPF+(1+\epsilon^{-1})G^TPG,$$ 
I read it in an article and I am still confused. 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange. I guess $F$, $G$, $P$ are matrices and $\epsilon>0$ is a scalar. Do you confirm this? In which sense should we interpret the $\le$? Element-wise?

Comment: Could you add a link to the article?

Comment: P is positive definite matrix, and <= means semi positive definite

Comment: What does it mean $\leq$ means semi-positive definite? Means that $A \geq 0$ is $A$ positive semi-definite?